# if statement not working.Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, arraylist

I'm a beginner with java and I don't know whats wrong with   my code.   Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

This code should check if any element of the array is less than `tc`, then its value should be incremented.

```
int pay1  = 190;
int pay2  = 1175;
int pay3  = 455;
int pay4  = 345;
int tc    = 400;
int[] pay = { pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4 };

for(int i = 0; i < pay.length; i++)
{
    if(pay[i] < tc)
    {
        pay[i] = pay[i]++;
        System.out.println(pay[i]+",");
    }
}
```

Comment: what this code suppose to do, and where is the error or weird behaviour??

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: This is not off topic, this is a valid question and shows a thing that should NOT be done in Java.

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
pay[i] = pay[i]++;
```

To:

```
pay[i]++;
```

Don't try to modify (++) and assign (=) in the same line or bad things happen. In this case it does the increment, then reassigns the original value.

This code:

```
int i = 0;
i = i++;
```

Produces this bytecode (javap -c ):

```
   0: iconst_0     
   1: istore_1    
   2: iload_1    
   3: iinc 1, 1  
   6: istore_1
```

Which means:

```
0: put zero on the stack
1: put the zero into i
2: put the value of i (0) onto the stack
3: increment i by 1 (i now has a value of 1)
6: store the value on the stack (0) into i (i now has a value of 0)
```

Comment: See updated answer @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 _An array access expression refers to a **variable** that is a component of an array._